# Is there a .cwl file for tkz-euclide package?

Tags: texstudio, tkz-euclide

Texstudio is highlighting all commands from tkz-euclide package. Is there a .cwl file for tkz-euclide package or I must create one?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (2020 Jan 8), there is no cwl file for `tkz-euclide`. You can check the full list of cwl files in [texstudio's repo](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/tree/master/completion), and welcome to contribute to texstudio.

Answer (score 1):

There are now cwl files for each of the `tkz-*` packages in the [completion folder](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/tree/master/completion) of TeXStudio's repository.